# Docker push failed from Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, dockerhub

I am new to GitLab and I want create a Gitlab CI pipeline which builds the Docker image and basically pushes it to my Dockerhub. I created a Free account in Gitlab and created a simple pipeline. Below is my pipeline.

Below are the Environment Variables (Note: I'm pushing to DockerHub)

[image]

[image]

But it says login failed. Username and password is correct

[image]

Do I need to create a Token ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try logging into docker hub using the credentials present in CI/CD variables?

Comment: Hello now Login is succeeded but now I get a different error. Permission denied. I uploaded the image.

Comment: Please check if you have the permission to push images to `devops` repository

Comment: The repo is public

Comment: Do we need a token to push the image to the reposiory?

Comment: Here is a similar issue - https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1689. Apparently `docker logout; docker login;` fixes the issue for many people. If you have access to the GitLab instance, could you try this?

Answer (score 0):

is the branch running the pipeline protected? since protected variables are seen only in protected branches and tags in gitlab